# Need help in function in Python

Tags: python, function

I am reviewing below code and having difficulty to understand why  `digit = values[squares]` is in `def eliminate(values)` function. Can someone explain why it is done?

Thanks

```
def cross(A,B):
    return [a+b for a in A for b in B]

digits = '123456789'
rows = 'ABCDEFGHI'
cols = digits
squares = cross(rows,cols)
unitlist = ([cross(rows,c)for c in cols]+[cross(r,cols)for r in rows]+
         [cross(rows,cols)for rows in('ABC','DEF','GHI')for cols in('123','456','789')])
units = dict((s,[u for u in unitlist if s in u])for s in squares)
peers = dict((s, set(sum(units[s],[]))-set([s])) for s in squares)
grid = '..3.2.6..9..3.5..1..18.64....81.29..7.......8..67.82....26.95..8..2.3..9..5.1.3..'

def grid_values(grid):
    values =[]
    for c in grid:
        if c == '.':
            values.append(digits)
        elif c in digits:
            values.append(c)
    assert len(grid)==81
    return dict(zip(squares,grid))

def eliminate(values):
    solved_values =[squares for squares in values.keys() if len(values[squares])==1]
    for squares in solved_values:
        digit = values[squares]
    for peer in peers[squares]:
        values[peer]=values[peer].replace(digit,'')
    return values
```

Comment: never use `sum(units[s],[])` it's super-slow use itertools.chain

Comment: What is the purpose of the function? If you are reviewing this code and you don't know what the reason for that line is, you could ask the author of the code you're reviewing.

Comment: The purpose of this code is to solve sudoku puzzle. My assumption is, the squares that has one value needs to be removed from values[peer]. But I don't understand why digit = values[squares] is there.

Comment: Seems that the for loop before takes squares which have a value on it and takes the digit from that square using the statement you don't understand

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example:

```
for squares in solved_values:
    digit = values[squares]
```

can be simplified to:

```
digit = values[squares[-1]]
```

`digit` is used later on in the function, so it seems to be important, but that loop does not need to be a loop, as it seems you've come to understand.